# React select does not work in Swiper component?

Tags: reactjs, select, swiper.js

I installed Swiper.js in my React project, and I want to use select in swiper component, but it's not working.

How I can use this select component?

###### This is 'swiper' code.

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
    
    <Swiper
      slidesPerView={4}         // slide number
      pagination={{ clickable: true }}
      touchStartPreventDefault = {false}  
      allowTouchMove={true}               
      observer={true}
      observeParents={true}             
      parallax={true}
      watchSlidesProgress={true}
    >
      {cardDatas.map((cardData, index) => {
        return (
          <SwiperSlide
            key={index}
          >
              <Card data={cardData} />
          </SwiperSlide>
        );
      })}
    </Swiper>
```

###### 'card component' code is too long to show all, so I am showing this snippet.

```
const options = [
    {
        label: 'name',
        value: 'name',
    },
    {
        label: 'gender',
        value: 'gender',
    },
];
    
export default function Card({ data }: { data: CardData }) {
    return (
      <Select
        width="63px"
        height="23px"
        options={options}
        defaultValue={duration}
        onChange={newValue => {
          console.log(newValue);
        }}
        className="text-center text-[12px] text-white"
      />
    );
}
```

I added the `OnChange()` event to the select component and used console.log() but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues, first of all the click-event isn't passed through the slider, and therefor select never gets the event.

You could disable the clicks on the slider by adding the following as described in [this git issue](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/1152):

```
preventClicks={false}
preventClicksPropagation={false}
```

---

But then the menu of select is *below* the slide, so we'll need to add some styling:

```js
<Select
    options={[
        { value: "foo", label: "foo" },
        { value: "bar", label: "bar" },
    ]}
    menuIsOpen={true}
    styles={{
        menu: base => ({ ...base, zIndex: '500 !important', position: 'relative' }) ,
        menuList: base => ({ ...base, zIndex: '500 !important' }),
        menuPortal: base => ({ ...base, zIndex: '500 !important' }) ,
    }}
    // ....
```

---

Combining those allows we me to use the React Select as expected
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problems when using these two libraries together in my project.

I was not able to right click and open the dropdown of react-select when it is in swiper slides.

You may wanna add these option/props to you Swiper like this

```
<Swiper
  preventClicks={false}
  simulateTouch={false}
  {
    ...otherProps
  }
>
 {
  /* ... 
    Your slides
  */
 }
</Swiper>
```

This allows the click events to be properly triggered inside the swiper, But this you may lose the ability to drag and scroll, So keep that in mind.